# Detecting list items not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small collection of list items:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Each list item is clickable. When an item is clicked, I'd like to hide all the other items that were NOT clicked.

```
$('.locations li').click(function() {

    // hide list items NOT clicked        

});
```

Anyone know how I can detect that?

Answer (score 3):

Hide all elements and then show the current one. The following should do the trick.

```
$('.locations li').click(function() {

    $('.locations li').hide();
    $(this).show();     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('ul.list li ').click(function(){
  $('ul.list li').hide(); // Hide the elements
  $(this).show(); // Show the clicked element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Answer (score 0):

Easy if you try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/zq0q77qu/

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('li').not($(this)).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of the above answer would be:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq0q77qu/2/

This is more efficient because you are just doing the query of the  items once.
Note the query for siblings, as the above answer would give you every  tag on your page, as of that I expect that you don't want.

```
$('li').click(function() {
 $(this).siblings().hide();   
});
```